# How to remove old house number

Tags: stucco

I have an old metal framed house number that looks like it is embedded in the stucco (see image).

Looking for a way to remove it without damaging the wall too much.
I'm planning to put a new ceramic number tile which is about the same size. So I hope not to damage the paint around it too much.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

First, use a hammer and chisel to cut the stucco tight to the old sign. Try to undercut at 45 degrees so that when the sign pops off it will not pull any more of the stucco with it. Once you have a clean-edged rectangular depression, fill it flush with a wood block and some stucco product. You want a waterproof patch.
If your new sign is a bit too small you can build a "picture frame" around the sign. Add the frame after mounting the new sign, or attach the sign to a larger thin substrate with the frame as one piece..

Comment: An old sharp wood chisel will give you a narrow cut with less breakage. In addition to my good wood chisels, I keep on hand an old chisel that I call a "sacrificial" chisel.

Answer (score 1):

Found a lot of details about this classic San Francisco house number [here](https://sunnysidehistory.org/2020/07/15/the-little-sculpture-affixed-your-house-anton-fazekas/)
After understanding the structure, you can see it can usually be removed without force, with some unscrewing of old rusted screws.